# Troubleshooting a JS code snippet that receives error message. Verify if the error is correct?

Tags: javascript

This particular chunk of code is receiving an error of a missing semi-colon. What is odd is that the code itself is a direct duplicate of code that is saving without the error in another file.

This is the only message I am receiving from the compiler (Hubspot). The error is supposedly happening on the first line. I am limited in my Javascript knowledge and thus am unable to verify with certainty that the error message I am receiving is correct. Could it be an incorrect error? If it is not, could someone help me with correcting what is causing the error?

Thanks in advance.

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
if (isIE) {         
  $("#svg >g, #logos, #logos > g, g.text, .services-svg, .services-svg > g, #a-experience-svg-figure,#experience-a-svg-group a.paragraph.link")
     .each(function() {
                $(this).attr('transform', $(this).css('transform'));
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code fragment are not problem with semicolon.